# Many of the time getting "result_code" as "BadImage" when uploading image of 24bit RGB PNG image to vuforia

Tags: image, augmented-reality, vuforia, badimageformatexception

Many of the time getting **"result_code" as "BadImage" when uploading image of 24bit RGB PNG image** to **vuforia**. If i am converting same image to JPEG then its getting uploaded properly. So not able to understand whats issue with image.(All the JPEG images are getting uploaded properly. **only issue with many of PNG images**.)

I had done some RnD
“BadImage” Unprocessable Entity (422) Image corrupted or format not supported (target POST/PUT response)
but not able to identify the issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Try running `pngcheck` on your images to see if they are faulty.

Comment: Thanks @MarkSetchell I checked image with pngcheck. It was 32bit image.  OK: mario.png (1473x1854, 32-bit RGB+alpha, non-interlaced, 83.8%). even after converting to 24bit from photoshop its not converting to 24bit. So i can have some alternative if some how i get this "bit" information using Javascript. Is there any solution for same?

Comment: I presume the reason Photoshop cannot convert your image to 24 bit is that it contains transparency - an *alpha* layer. It's hard to be sure what the problem is without seeing the image. Does `vuforia` handle images with transparency? If not, you will need to remove the transparency... click Layer->Layer Mask->From Transparency, then right click on the mask in the layer pallet and select Delete Layer Mask

Comment: @MarkSetchell I already tried with non transparent same image. But as its 32bit png image. So its not allowing me. I have 2 option please let me know if you have solution of any of one. 1.I need to conver any of png image to 24bit depth image and can use same image for vuforia or 2. I need to restrict user from front-end(javascript) to upload only jpeg image or 24bit png image.